# Set a placeholder and rename 'browse' button

Tags: symfony4, vichuploaderbundle

I use Vich Uploader bundle for SF 4.0 in Bootstrap. I would like to set a placeholder and rename 'browse' button.

I have tried to :

- Use 'placehoder' attribute (FormType.php)

```
{{ form_widget(form.imageFile, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': "Please attach picture"}} ) }}
```

- Add 'placeholder' option (error) or label option (change nothing)

**How can I do that ?**

Please, find below my code

***FormType.php***

```php
->add('imageFile', VichFileType::class, [])
```

_form.html.twig

```
{{ form_widget(form.imageFile, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}} ) }}
{{ form_errors(form.imageFile) }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using bootstrap 4; I use webpack to recompile bootstrap for my needs and I add this scss code before including bootstrap.scss:

```css
$custom-file-text: (
        en: "Browse",
        it: "Sfoglia"
);

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

This way I can translate or change the file upload button. You can personalize other aspect of Bootstrap using this method, see [Bootstrap online documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults)

If you don't use webpack you should obtain the same result by adding this css after including bootstrap css

```css
.custom-file-input:lang(en) ~ .custom-file-label::after {
  content: "Browse";
}

.custom-file-input:lang(it) ~ .custom-file-label::after {
  content: "Sfoglia";
}
```

One entry is required per language supported by your Symfony 4 app